# How to prove "if lim[f/g]=0, then f(n) is o(g(n))”?

Tags: limits, algorithms, asymptotics

[This link is my previous attempt to prove this.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1450997/can-someone-check-my-process-of-proving-if-limf-g-0-then-fn-ogn)

---

Question: if $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=0$, then $f(n)$ is $o(g(n))$.

---

My proof:

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=0$

$\Rightarrow$
$\displaystyle{0}\le{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}}\lt{c}$
, $\forall{c}\gt{0}$

$\Rightarrow$
${0}\le{\frac{\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(n)}{\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}g(n)}}\lt{c}$
, $\forall{c}\gt{0}$, $f$ and $g$ is real-valued function

$\Rightarrow$
$\displaystyle{0}\le{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{f(n)}}\lt{c\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}g(n)}$
, $\forall{c}\gt{0}$, $f$ and $g$ is real-valued function

$\Rightarrow$
$\displaystyle{0}\le{f(n)}\lt{{c}\cdot{g(n)}}$
, $\forall{c}\gt{0}$, $f$ and $g$ is real-valued function
, $\forall{n}\ge{N}$, where N is big enough.

$\Rightarrow$
$\displaystyle{0}\le{f(n)}\lt{{c}\cdot{g(n)}}$
, $\forall{c}\gt{0}$, $\forall{n}\ge{N}$, $\exists{N\gt0}$

$\Rightarrow$
$f(n)\in{o(g(n))}$ $(\because o(g(n))\equiv\{f(x):\forall c>0, \exists n_0>0$  s.t. $0\le f(n)\lt cg(n), \forall n\ge n_0\})$

$\Rightarrow$
$f(n)=o(g(n))$

## $\therefore$ if $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=0$, then $f(n)$ is $o(g(n))$.

---

Is there any problem in my proof process?

I extremely want to prove this [rigorously and mathematically].

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error occurs when you assert that

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = \frac{\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)}{\lim_{n \to \infty} g(n)},
$$

which is not true in general. Take, for example, $f(n) = n$ and $g(n) = n^2$.

The second error occurs when you try to multiply both sides of an inequality by $\lim_{n \to \infty} g(n)$, which may be $\infty$. This is not valid.

Third, the expression

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) < c \lim_{n \to \infty} g(n)
$$

can only be true if $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)$ is *finite*. This is not one of the usual assumptions on the theorem you are trying to prove, so writing an expression which depends on it is not valid.

Comment: I got what I was wrong. Thank you, I should think more about this problem intently.